# How do you find the method in a multiple dynamic dispatch system, how is it implemented under the hood?

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures

Wikipedia doesn't very much go into enough detail describing exactly how this feature is implemented:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch

Here's my understanding so far. For example, say I have this:

```
class Car {
  speed: 0

  drive(speed) {
    this.speed = speed
  }
}

car = new Car
car.drive(10)
```

When I create a new instance of the car, you can imagine it like a struct, perhaps with the type included in the runtime:

```
type: Car<#123> // <- memory address 123 starts this record
speed: 10
```

But the method is stored somewhere else perhaps, like in a table. You lookup the car type in a table, and then for the type look up the method. The question is, how exactly does this work, what data structures are typically involved?

For example, the type "Car" is really an integer (if you want to optimize). Let's say Car == 456. Then we go to a table to find the car type methods:

```
typeTable[456]
```

This type table could be a hash table or an array or a B+tree, for example. Let's say it's an array of pointers. Then that gives us *something* that tells us the methods:

```
CarType: {
  drive: functionPointer
}
```

The question is, how do you determine this drive function from this *record*? Would you tell by the drive *string* in a hash table? That seems inefficient. What else could be done?

You might not know the type of the record at compile time. Say for example this:

```
main(argv) {
  let Type = typeFromString(argv[0])
  let car = new Type
  car.drive(10)
}
```

How would it find such a method?

Even if the dynamic type was typed something generic, how would it find the specific method for the actual type it is?

```
main(argv) {
  let Drivable = typeFromString(argv[0]) as Drivable
  let car = new Drivable
  car.drive(10)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structures and lookup methods differ by language, but the lookup operation is always very simple and very fast.  No trees or other fancy data structures are involved.

In C++, the every object with virtual methods has a hidden pointer to its virtual table, and the virtual table is an array of function pointers (plus some other stuff you don't care about).  The compiler assigns a constant index to each declared virtual method, which is its index in *every* virtual table in which it can appear, so when you say:

```
car->drive(speed);
```

The code that is generated is just like

```
(car->__vtable[DRIVE_INDEX])(car,speed);
```

Multiple inheritance can lead to methods with conflicting indexes, and C++ puts up with some idiosyncrasies to make this work for multiple inheritance situations.  The pointer to the base class inside a subclass isn't always the same as the pointer to the subclass, for example.

These idiosyncrasies are a lot of the traditional reason why some languages prefer only single inheritance.

Eventually, compiler writers came up with good ways to support multiple inheritance without the weirdness that C++ has, and these have been adopted by languages like java.

One good trick, for example, is to replace the method index with a hash.  The code is almost the same:

```
(car->__vtable[DRIVE_HASH])(DRIVE_ID, car, speed)
```

... but now, when a vtable contains methods with conflicting hashes, the code that the compiler generates for the implementation just checks the method ID value to disambiguate.